# Build Tree view with checkbox using material and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have this code :

```
const TREE_DATA_JSON = {
idManager: 1,
label: 'Manager',
descendants: [
    {
        idManager: 2,
        label: 'Des 1',
        areaManagers: [
            {
                idManager: 3,
                label: 'Manager 1'
            },
            {
                idManager: 4,
                label: 'Manager 2'
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

};

```
@Injectable()
export class ChecklistDatabase {
dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

get data(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

constructor() {
    this.initialize();
}

initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.
    const data = this.buildFileTree(TREE_DATA_JSON, 0);

    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
}

/**
 * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
 * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
 */
buildFileTree(obj: object, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
        const value = obj[key];
        const node = new TodoItemNode();
        node.item = key;

        if (value != null) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
            } else {
                node.item = value;
            }
        }

        return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
}
```

}
But I have the tree view like this :

[image]

Have you an idea how to modify `buildFileTree` ? The tree I get from : https://stackblitz.com/angular/gabkadkvybq?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts.

Thx in advance for your message and sorry for my english

I want to display something like this :

- Manager

  - Des 1

    - Manager 1
    - Manager 2

My stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdflat

Comment: Hi, Could you please let us know what is your expected output. Since the Stackbliz example which you have shared works as expected shown in the image which you shared.

Comment: You seem to have linked the stock example provided by the Angular Material team without any modifications. Please attempt to implement the requirement on your own first. You could then post a question when you come across a hurdle.

Comment: Hi @KIsdskldsd, I guess instead of using ```FlatTree``` you should use ```NestedTree```
Please have a look at this [Example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#nested-tree)

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdflat

Comment: @MichaelD I added my stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdflat

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that when you select a parent, you automatically want to select each of its descendants as well. if you would like to change this behavior to simply **show** the descendants once a parent is checked bot not actually auto-check the descendants, let me know and I can make that change. It's a fairly small change.

I've also added an event listener to this code that automatically unchecks all checkboxes when a related ancestor required for its visibility is unchecked. Run the snippet above to see this in action.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const TREE_DATA_JSON = [{
  idManager: 1,
  label: 'Manager',
  descendants: [{
    idManager: 2,
    label: 'Des 1',
    areaManagers: [{
        idManager: 3,
        label: 'Manager 1'
      }, {
        idManager: 4,
        label: 'Manager 2'
      },
    ]
  }]
}];

function buildTree(form, arr) {
  function fetchUniqueArr(obj) { return obj[Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !['idManager', 'label'].includes(key))]; }
  function buildTreeHTML(arr, nested = false) {
    return arr.map((field,i) => `${i?'<br>':''}<input id="field-${field.idManager}" type="checkbox"><label for="field-${field.idManager}">${field.label}</label>` + (Object.keys(field).length === 3 ? `<br><div class="nested-fields">${buildTreeHTML(fetchUniqueArr(field), true)}</div>` : '')).join('');
  }
  form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', buildTreeHTML(arr));
}

document.addEventListener('change', e => e.target?.matches('form input[type="checkbox"]') && e.target.nextElementSibling?.nextElementSibling?.nextElementSibling?.matches('.nested-fields') && e.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(field => field.checked = e.target.checked));

buildTree(form, TREE_DATA_JSON);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
form, .nested-fields {
  display: block;
}
.nested-fields {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
input:not(:checked) + label + br + .nested-fields {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form></form>
```

If you're wanting to support "indeterminate" checkbox values, where a parent is "half checked" when only some of its children are checked, that functionality isn't supported natively in HTML/CSS/JS, but there are several libraries around to help you achieve that. For further reading and examples on indeterminate checkbox lists,  check out this CSS-Tricks article by Chris Coyier, [Indeterminate Checkboxes](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/)

Comment: Is not like expected. I should use material treeview. Here my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdflat

Comment: No worries, just a vanilla solution^ for any interested in doing this themselves without an API. With a little more work, we could get this working, even in Vanilla, with indeterminate values. I am also noticing some issues with that material treevioew when working with it further: https://i.imgur.com/Mth97cF.png